# How can i bulk insert with the filename changing

Tags: sql, azure, azure-blob-storage

So the problem is this I get a csv file everyday. How can I import the the csv file without the filename being hardcoded. here is the code I'm using now

```
  BULK INSERT [dbo].[MyData]
  FROM 'input.csv'
  WITH ( 
  DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
  FORMAT      = 'CSV',
  FIRSTROW    = 2
  );
  END
```

Comment: simply you rename then csv file which is you hard coded in that query

Comment: Refer to the link [Bulk insert from changing file names.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7720060-8f03-4dd8-a9b3-0247822137ca/bulk-insert-from-changing-file-names?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Dynamic SQL.
Try with this code:

```
DECLARE @FilePath Varchar(200)
SET @FilePath = 'C:\YOUR PATH HERE\input.csv'
EXEC(BULK INSERT [dbo].[MyData]
FROM '''+ @FilePath +'''
  WITH ( 
  DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
  FORMAT      = 'CSV',
  FIRSTROW    = 2)
```

I hope this helps you!